# Get N on screen when trying to access developer options

Tags: developer-options

Cannot access Developer Options on Asus Zenphone 3 (Android 7.1.1):

- Settings
- About
- Tap 6 times on Android Version

All I get is an 'N' on the screen:

[image: IMG:]

Comment: The [tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/developer-options/info) of the tag used by you has the answer. It always helps to read that and questions on that tag

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are hitting the wrong area to get developers options. Within setting/about phone/software/build number you need to hit `Build number` 7 times to enable the developers options. Hitting Android Version multiple times enables a google cookie for the android version.

Answer (score 4):

- This screen shows your current android version status and further tapping on it will enable Android Easter egg. The N means you're using Android Nougat (7.1) on your device.
- to enable developer options, go to settings->about phone, tap on build number multiple times (about 7 times), on completes it shows a message that you have enabled developer options.

Features:

- At the top of the Developer options screen, you can toggle the options on and off.
- Next option is USB debugging. This allows Android Studio and other SDK tools to recognize your device when connected via USB, so you can use the debugger and other tools.
- Also contains several options to set audio, networking, display, media, monitoring, apps tweaks for your device.

N.B : please be careful on this option 'OEM unlocking' in developer options. If got enabled unexpectedly, your device will continue in boot loop. This option is often used to root device.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options)